# Send push notification to a specific endpoint

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

I want to send a push notification from an android app direct to an android endpoint using amazon SNS. I'd like to know how to do that if I have only the GCM token of the endpoint (if it is impossible, what I have to have to do so?). I have to know how to register the endpoint on amazon SNS from the endpoint app too, if it is necessary. I am using Android Studio. I am newbie on app development and need this as soon as possible!!

Thank you
Andre

Comment: Enjoy the [**docs**](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html). Got examples, samples, many things you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following method to register in amazon sns from android device.Before u go for registration you have to get 
1.access_key_id
2.secret_access_key
3.application Arn
4.API key from gcm

then use following code:

```
 private String createEndpoint(String token) {

            String endpointArn = null;
            try {
                System.out.println("Creating endpoint with token " + token);
                CreatePlatformEndpointRequest cpeReq = new CreatePlatformEndpointRequest().withPlatformApplicationArn(applicationArn).withToken(token);
                CreatePlatformEndpointResult cpeRes = client.createPlatformEndpoint(cpeReq);
                endpointArn = cpeRes.getEndpointArn();
            } catch (InvalidParameterException ipe) {
                String message = ipe.getErrorMessage();
                System.out.println("Exception message: " + message);
                Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*Endpoint (arn:aws:sns[^ ]+) already exists " + "with the same Token.*");
                Matcher m = p.matcher(message);
                if (m.matches()) {
                    // the endpoint already exists for this token, but with
                    // additional custom data that
                    // CreateEndpoint doesn't want to overwrite. Just use the
                    // existing endpoint.
                    endpointArn = m.group(1);
                } else {
                    // rethrow exception, the input is actually bad
                    throw ipe;
                }
            }
            storeEndpointArn(endpointArn);
            return endpointArn;
        }
```